# Suggestions for a cheap/free .NET library for doing Zip with AES encryption?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encryption, zip

I'm trying to find an zip compression and encryption component with [encryption suitable for use by the US Federal Government](http://www.networkworld.com/careers/2004/0315manonline.html), so I can't use Zip 2.0 encryption, it has to be AES or the like.  I've already found [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) (can't do AES encyrption), and [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads.asp) (can do AES encryption, but costs money).  Am I missing any other options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How much would you be willing to pay for AES in DotNetZip? 
;)

DotNetZip supports AES Encryption, with 128 or 256-bit keys.

http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip

Example code:

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt"); // no password for this entry

    // use a password for subsequent entries
    zip.Password= "This.Encryption.is.FIPS.197.Compliant!";
    zip.Encryption= EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.AddFile("Rawdata-2008-12-18.csv");
    zip.Save("Backup-AES-Encrypted.zip");
  }
```

The AES-encrypted zip files produced by DotNetZip can be read and extracted by WinZip, and vice-versa.

You can also just create regular zip files without encryption.

oh, and it's free.

Comment: Does any of you have a way to see what method was used to encrypt an archive? If I open a generated archive with WinZip I see that it is indeed encrypted, but I have no way on telling with what algorithm (Zip2.0, AES128, AES256, etc.).

Comment: DotNetZip will tell you with the ZipFile.Encryption property on a zip file you have read.  I don't know how to do it with WinZip.

Comment: I was really excited about this library, however we need to use the certified crypto providers such as `AesCryptoServiceProvider` vs the managed counterpart `AesManaged`. I think DotNetZip is using `RijndaelManaged` for backwards compatibility to .NET 2 :(

Comment: I've gotten FIPS compatibility out of DotNetZip, but only when I use `EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak`, not `EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256`.

Answer (score 6):

If money is a big issue, you could take an open source library like this http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip, which now has AES support

Answer (score 6):

What about [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)?  It's open source under the LGPL (so should be usable in your project) and according to the spec it supports ZIP with AES encryption.

Comment: I like 7-zip, but it requires either launching a process (to run it from command line) or COM/unmanaged code interop.

Comment: Actually, they have the LZMA SDK which now has C# code to use it as well: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out this awesome article on the [Stream Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163290.aspx).  It not only defines a cool way to link streams to each other in a multithreaded fashion, the example used is compression followed by encryption.

Comment: The link is broken now, the article seems to be in the February 2008 MSDN issue, Column ".NET Matters: Stream Pipeline". http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineFebruary2008en-us.chm

Answer (score 1):

You can use #ZipLib (https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/), which is a lightweight alternative to DotNetZipLib.

It offers the FastZip class, which reduces compression of a folder on the HDD with AES encryption to 2-3 lines of code.

See the wiki for reference:
https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip

If you need more features, #ZipLib gets a bit more complicated than DotNetZipLib, but the latter created corrupted ZIP files in my case, so i use SharpZipLib anyways.